# Making Junit Reuse Tomcat context.xml

Tags: tomcat, junit

I am not an expert in java but right now I have inherited some code that I need to make work. My goal is to run the source test suite. The (creation of the) beans needed for the tests require some environment settings. These settings are in tomcat-root-dir/conf/context.xml. These environment settings are used by tomcat to deploy the web application.

I want to reuse tomcat-root-dir/conf/context.xml with junit, or otherwise make the testsuite work. Is there some standard way to parse context.xml for junit? I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: You could make local build/system specific variable that specifies where you have tomcat and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a standard way to parse XML, so you're free to read any file you wish and parse XML.

I'm assuming that you want a JNDI lookup for a data source or something like that.  The problem, of course, would be that you're coupled to Tomcat if you persist along this line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, your assumption about the JNDI lookup is correct.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit4 provides Rule **ExternalResource** to handle resource: See [ExternalResource Core Rule](http://www.catosplace.net/blogs/personal/?p=187).

Answer (score 0):

We have taken the approach of using an embedded glassfish server. This would not reuse the tomcat context.xml but will be able to access external resources.

Answer (score 0):

[TomcatJNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/TomcatJNDI) solves this problem. It can process Tomcat's configuration files and creates the same JNDI environment as Tomcat does, but without starting a server. So you can run classes with dependencies on Tomcat's JNDI environment in e. g. JUnit tests.

```
TomcatJNDI tomcatJNDI = new TomcatJNDI();
tomcatJNDI.processContextXml(new File("tomcat-root-dir/conf/context.xml");
tomcatJNDI.start();
```

Then your classes can lookup the DataSource as when they would run in Tomcat.

[More about TomcatJNDI can be found here.](https://github.com/h-thurow/TomcatJNDI)